# how can I get image tag from different image views on tapping on it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, imageview, tap

I want to used image view from nos. of image views in scroll view on single tapping any particular image view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are insistent on using images instead of buttons you can use Gesture Recognizer. Create an imageView and enable its userInteraction

```
UIImageView *testImageView              =   [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage"]];
testImageView.frame                     =   CGRectMake(30.0,30.0,60.0,40.0);
testImageView.tag                       =   30;
testImageView.userInteractionEnabled    =   TRUE;
[tempPlotView addSubview: testImageView];
[testImageView release];
```

Now allocate a gesture Recognizer object and add it to your imageView...

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *testGesture =   [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singletap:)];
[testGesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[testImageView addGestureRecognizer: testGesture];
[testGesture     release];
```

Now in the selector "singleTap" you can do whatever your action is..

```
-(void)singleTap:(UIImageView*)sender{
    if(sender.tag == 30){
        //do your stuff here...
    }
}
```

Hope this help...cheers....

Comment: [imageView1 addGestureRecognizer: testGesture]; for this tapped function is not getting executed but when i use [self.view addGestureRecognizer: testGesture]; it executes the tapped function

Comment: @Spikydude are you sure you are enabling the userInteraction of imageView. You have to add the GestureRecognizer to imageView itself,not to self.view. Also check whether the parentView of imageView has userInteraction.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use image views, you could use UIButtons with image views as their content.

That way, you'll get a callback when a given image is tapped with a reference to the button. From there you should be able to get the tag of that which has been tapped!

I hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

Create a button and set image as background.while creating button you can set tag like

```
button.tag=yourtag;//your tag integer value 
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

  [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and implement this function in your clss

```
 - (void)buttonTouched:(UIButton *)sender 
   {
NSLog(@"touched %i",[sender tag]);
   }
```

while tapping the particular button this function will get called.

Answer (score 0):

You can do according to what Nick has suggested.
Or else,  you can create a subclass of the imageview. Set frame and tag to it.
In touchesEnded method of this custom class, you can find which imageview it is based on its tag.